# What types of cycle/recursive dependency problems can occur with dependency injection systems?

Tags: java, algorithm, kotlin, recursion, dependency-injection

I am implementing a dependency injection library, and so far I finished the library as far as running applications without recursive dependency problems.
I am looking to implement protections against cycles so the app could be stopped as soon as a problem is detected, ideally with a helpful message on which classes cause the cycle.

A typical contract for most DI libraries is this:
For each type you can request a `Provider<T>` with a `get()` method.
(all constructor injection etc. is just a syntax sugar on top if this contract)

They should be thread-safe and support concurrency at all times.

Two types of bindings, one is a "factory" creating objects on demand, and the second is "singleton" which can only be initialized once.

If I am correct there are two separate kind of problems to handle:

```kotlin
@Singleton 
class A(val dep: B)
@Singleton
class B(val dep: A)
```

As singleton construction is synchronized on the binding object, that should result in a classic deadlock.

```kotlin
class A(val dep: B)
class B(val dep: A)
```

That to me should result in a StackOverflowError.

What's the best way to detect these cycles and provide useful exceptions pointing to source of the cycle?
Do you think there's a 3rd type of recursive problem to handle that cannot be generalized to these 2 cases?

Comment: Note that I am trying to take inspiration from Guice on that, but I have a feeling that this can be implemented or at least _explained_ in much simpler terms than in case of Guice.

Comment: [SingletonScope.java](https://github.com/google/guice/blob/e960b66d3d5931b9cb1aebd49e452e2c489a921e/core/src/com/google/inject/internal/SingletonScope.java)
[Initializer.java](https://github.com/google/guice/blob/e960b66d3d5931b9cb1aebd49e452e2c489a921e/core/src/com/google/inject/internal/Initializer.java)
[CycleDetectingLock.java](https://github.com/google/guice/blob/e960b66d3d5931b9cb1aebd49e452e2c489a921e/core/src/com/google/inject/internal/CycleDetectingLock.java)